# how to kill the session when user closed the browser without logout

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing one aspnet application in that i am using Sessions. if user login into the application and click on logout here i am closing session.

suppose if the user doesn't click on the logout and he close the browser. how to kill the session when user closed the browser without logout

Comment: Rippo,what wrong in my asking questions Is there any mistake?

Comment: Nothing wrong in asking questions, I salute you, although if people go to the trouble to answer then it makes sense to at least accept some as the correct answer. Also it helps other S.O. users find answers to common questions, after all it is a community driven site!

Comment: Excellent, hope you get a good answer, maybe you can revisit some of your old questions and accept answers there! :)

Answer (score 7):

Very difficult task:

- use sessions with very smalll timeout /you will have expiration/
- use hidden script/iframe to ping server /you will have connection/
- handle onunload event in window /can be bypassed/

Code sample:

```
window.onunload = function ()  
{    
    if((window.event.clientX<0) && (window.event.clientY<0)) {

       window.open("logoff.aspx");                  
    }    
}
```

Comment: +1 I have used `window.onunload` before but still found some problems esp with bots, mobile devices etc. In the end I changed my business logic.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way your application can know that the user has closed the browser. Session will be closed based on Session.Timeout

If the user does not refresh or request a page within the time-out period, the session ends.

Comment: that we can do.but how to restrict when user close the browser?

Answer (score 1):

You can define what should happen when a Session expires in Global.asax.cs.

```
protected void Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do stuff here...
}
```

Edit: There is no way for the web server to know that you have closed a web browser.

Comment: You cannot guarantee this will ***ALWAYS*** work as a application recycle will not fire this event. Also note is that Session_End is fired only in InProc (in-process) mode.